# JOptionPane variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, joptionpane

I'm sorry the code is so long, I just need to know what I'm missing to initialize all my decisions. The compiler is complaining about my variable not being initialized. Thank you.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SemesterProject
{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

   String SemesterProject =
"Hello and welcome to Juans adventure story! Your choices throughout this story will bring your doom or your salvation!\n"+
"No one has been able to complete this story and lived to tell the tale, but maybe you will be the first one!.\n"+

"Our story begins in the small town of Badow. Many people in the town spread rumors of brave adventurers that\n"+
"go on the quest to solve the mysterious riddles of the abandond castle at the top of the hill.\n"+
"No one really knows who or what lies at the heart of the castle. Legend says that monsters guards the\n"+
"the many riches once owned by the family that died there, so many years ago.\n"+

"The Castle is full of dizzing turns and hidden corridors and dangerous monsters. Many adventureres \n"+
"have gone insane because of how they lose their way or go get stuck. It is the hardes quest known to man.\n"+
"The quest for you is to go to the castle, solve the riddles and claim the riches.\n"+
"The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here.\n"+
"Be careful. Watch your back and always mark your trail because you never know what you will find next.\n"+
"If for some crazy reason you end up successful in this task, you will not only get the riches in the castle but\n"+
"you will also be crowned the king of the town of Badow. If you die, you lose.\n"+

"The last thing you have to do is input some of your personal information so that we keep you in our records.\n";


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,SemesterProject);


String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please give us your first name.");

String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please give us your age.");

String weight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please give us your weight.");

String haircolor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please give us your hair color.");

String GPA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please give us your GPA.");

String favoritecolor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please give us your favorite color.");

String decision1,decision2,decision3,decision4,decision5,decision6;

decision1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Brave adventurer, welcome to the entrance of the abandoned castle of town Badow. At this moment\n"+
"You have a choice right now to give up and take a walk of shame back to the village, and to safety\n"+
"Or you can decide to go in and test your unique set of skills on the various challenges of the adventure\n"+
"ahead of you. Enter the number of your choice.You can either 1. Enter the castle 2. Stay behind.");

    if (decision1.equals("1"))
    {
        decision2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ("You find yourself at the entrance of the castle with a choice to go down a dark hall\n"+
        "or to the closest room on the right side. Be vary wary the darkness can make you lose your mind and go insane and remember\n"+
        "to keep track of were you are. 1. Into the room 2. Down the hall.");

        }
        else
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You go back to your boring life in the town, you wont be remembered by anything and you\n"+
             "lost your chance at getting the riches that lie deep in the castle. You lose.");
    }
    if (decision2.equals("1"))
    {
        decision3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ("You step into the room and find some medication and a lantern with some oil.\n"+
        "you also find a sword. You can choose now to go back to the dark hallway or to go down a hidden trap door in the room. It could be\n"+
        "a shortcut or it could lead somewhere dangerous. 1. Back down the hall 2. Take your chances with the trapdoor.");

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you should have looked in the room, you quickly lose your way and the darkness\n"+
                "makes you crazy.");
    }
    if (decision3.equals("1"))
    {
            decision4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            ("You are back in the hall slowly hearing the echoing sound of your footsteps\n"+
            "you head downstairs into what seems to be another hallway but this one full of barred rooms, kind of like a dungeon. There is\n"+
            "a skeleton body on the ground which seems to be of another failure by an adventurer in the castle. You reach the end of the hall\n"+
            "and there is two ways to go left or right. 1. Left 2. Right.");

        }
        else
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You squeeze through the trapdoor and fall down to the ground where  you find youself lost and disoriented\n"+
             "You dont know where you are and start to panic, you start becoming insane and die.");
            }
            if (decision4.equals("1"))
            {

                   decision5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                   ("You go left and hear a door open behind you, you panic and start to run\n"+
                   "you run intro different halls to try and escape but you trip. You just remembered that you have a sword with you and can now\n"+
                   "choose what to do 1. Take out sword and fight enemy 2. Get up and keep running.");
               }
               else
               {
                       JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You go right and get locked in behind you. You realize that there isnt anwhere to go\n"+
                       "and get lost in the darkest part of the castle and die alone.");

            }
            if (decision5.equals("1"))
            {

                decision6 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
("You were able to fight of the armored enemy. But something tells you that that isnt the last of them. You continue on down the\n"+"hall and see from the distance to what seems to be your first prize. It cant be that easy.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What variable? Can you post the error stack trace?

Comment: Is all the text really necessary? It makes the code really unreadable.

Comment: *"The compiler is complaining about my variable not being initialized."* 1) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 2) Compilers don't 'complain', they simply 'report'.  ;)

Comment: Thanks GOD! I finally discovered why `ResourceBundle`s are created in Java! Put your texts in a `.properties` files man, and just add a reference to them in your code, and you 1000 lines of code will be 10, and much readable! And don't try to torture yourself and us! Use an IDE (such as IDEA Community, Eclipse or Netbeans). It will mark compile issues, help you and the whole community!

Comment: Java does not assign any default values to **local** variables.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your `String` variables (`decision1`, `decision2`,...) as:

```
String decision1 = null, decision2 = null, decision3 = null, decision4 = null, decision5 = null, decision6 = null;
```

Note that you don't get a compile error for `decision1` because in the line

```
decision1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
```

it is being initialized.

Also, your program's logic is bad. If `decision1` is not `1`, then you will just show a message, but the program will continue to check the next condition:

```
if (decision2.equals("1"))
```

where you will get a `NullPointerException` because you are comparing `null` with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the decision variables as null.  Instead of:

```
String decision1,decision2,decision3,decision4,decision5,decision6;
```

Define the variables as:

```
String decision1 = null;
String decision2 = null;
String decision3 = null;
String decision4 = null;
String decision5 = null;
String decision6 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

decision2 is only being set if decision1 is equal to 1. I think you want to put the if statements for the other decisions inside of each other like below:

```
if (decision1.equals("1"))
{
    decision2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    ("You find yourself at the entrance of the castle with a choice to go down a dark hall\n"+
    "or to the closest room on the right side. Be vary wary the darkness can make you lose your mind and go insane and remember\n"+
    "to keep track of were you are. 1. Into the room 2. Down the hall.");

    if (decision2.equals("1"))
    {
    decision3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    ("You step into the room and find some medication and a lantern with some oil.\n"+
    "you also find a sword. You can choose now to go back to the dark hallway or to go down a hidden trap door in the room. It could be\n"+
    "a shortcut or it could lead somewhere dangerous. 1. Back down the hall 2. Take your chances with the trapdoor.");

        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you should have looked in the room, you quickly lose your way and the darkness\n"+
            "makes you crazy.");
}
    }
    else
    {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You go back to your boring life in the town, you wont be remembered by anything and you\n"+
         "lost your chance at getting the riches that lie deep in the castle. You lose.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane variable might not have been initialized
```

So keep in mind one thing that whenever you get such kind of error messages try to see that your variables are properly declared.

See when you try to use int variable it can give you error message if that variable is used in some computation. So try to initialize the variables like:

```
int a=0;
```

You can do the same thing with string variables also like:

```
String a=null;
```

**Returning to answer**

In your code you have just declared the variables , but the fact is that you have to actually initialize them.

Replace

```
String decision1,decision2,decision3,decision4,decision5,decision6;
```

By

```
String decision1=null,decision2=null,decision3=null,decision4=null,decision5=null,decision6=null;
```